# Modal verb 'May'

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

May flowers flourish in your garden!

What is wrong in this sentence? Grammarly says, that I have to change the verb form. It suggests that I write, 'May flower flourish in your garden' and not 'flowers'. When I put the article "the" in front of the flowers (May the flowers flourish in your garden), Grammarly accepts it. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: English grammar checking programs are not very good.  There's nothing grammatically wrong with "May flowers flourish in your garden."

Answer (score 1):

flower is a countable noun and you need "a" or "the" or just a plural form of "flowers"

ex. boy: A boy is playing on the ground. Boys are playing on the ground. The boy is playing on the ground or The boys are playing on the ground.

But 'Boy is playing on the ground' is not correct.

'May' is just an auxiliary verb which needs an infinitive(the original form of a verb) after it.

May you **live** long. May God **bless** you. These sentences express a wish by a speaker.

Comment: You're explaining the background, but you're not actually giving an answer to the question. Two comments have given the answer: Grammarly is purely and simply wrong.

Comment: The questioner may need "background". Comments are comments.

Comment: Yes, the questioner may indeed need background. But answers that don't answer aren't answers .

Comment: But answers that do answer are answers that the questioner may really need.